# VOIP API is not supported in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, sip, voip, android-wifi

Crash on bellow line when i used native SIP calling

> call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener,
>   30);

```
public SipAudioCall makeAudioCall(String localProfileUri,
            String peerProfileUri, SipAudioCall.Listener listener, int timeout)
            throws SipException {
        if (!isVoipSupported(mContext)) {
            throw new SipException("VOIP API is not supported");
        }
        try {
            return makeAudioCall(
                    new SipProfile.Builder(localProfileUri).build(),
                    new SipProfile.Builder(peerProfileUri).build(), listener,
                    timeout);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new SipException("build SipProfile", e);
        }
    }
```

Crash Logs.

```
08-01 13:26:54.627 9574-9574/com.example.android.sip I/WalkieTalk: Error when trying to close manager.
                                                                   android.net.sip.SipException: VOIP API is not supported
                                                                       at android.net.sip.SipManager.makeAudioCall(SipManager.java:368)
                                                                       at com.example.android.sip.WalkieTalkieActivity.initiateCall(WalkieTalkieActivity.java:213)
                                                                       at com.example.android.sip.WalkieTalkieActivity$5.onClick(WalkieTalkieActivity.java:324)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I tested on Device : Mi , Moto x

Answer (score 0):

the SIP Stack in Android is pretty outdated. See https://telestax.com/jain-sip-stack-for-android/.

I would recommend actually going at a higher level and use something like [restcomm-android-sdk](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk). If you really need to use the raw SIP Stack, you can still do so by using https://github.com/RestComm/jain-sip

Comment: I am getting lots of error in restcomm-android-sdk like as webrtc or other